# How can I remove all content in brackets except entirely numerical content?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I want to take a string and remove all occurrences of characters within square brackets:

`[foo]`,  `[foo123bar]`, and `[123bar]` should be removed

But I want to keep intact any brackets consisting of only numbers:

`[1]` and `[123]` should remain

I've tried a couple of things, to no avail:

```
text = text.replace(/\[^[0-9+]\]/gi, "");

text = text.replace(/\[^[\d]\]/gi, "");
```

Comment: Please also add the tag of the language you are using.

Comment: doesn't this work? `text.replace(/\[^[0-9]+\]/gi, "");` changed position of `+`. Sorry, it would not, it would only replace characters if there are no numeric characters in `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Here's how you would use it:

```
text = text.replace(/\[(?!\d+\])[^\[\]]+\]/g, "");
```

After `\[` locates an opening bracket, the lookahead, `(?!\d+\])` asserts that the brackets do not contain only digits.

Then, `[^\[\]]+` matches anything that's not square brackets, ensuring (for example) that you don't accidentally match "nested" brackets, like `[[123]]`.

Finally, `\]` matches the closing bracket.

Comment: Thanks - this is very helpful. I knew \d should be involved somewhere. Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/QL4UL/

Comment: Great, never heard about negative lookahead before. That's why I love SO.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need this:

```
text = text.replace(/\[[^\]]*[^0-9\]][^\]]*\]/gi, "");
```

Explanation: you want to keep those sequences within brackets that contain *only* numbers. An alternative way to say this is to *delete* those sequences that are 1) enclosed within brackets, 2) contain no closing bracket and 3) contain at least one non-numeric character. The above regex matches an opening bracket (`\[`), followed by an arbitrary sequence of characters except the closing bracket (`[^\]]`, note that the closing bracket had to be escaped), then a non-numeric character (also excluding the closing bracket), then an arbitrary sequence of characters except the closing bracket, then the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
import re
text = '[foo] [foo123bar] [123bar] [foo123] [1] [123]'
print re.sub('(\[.*[^0-9]+\])|(\[[^0-9][^\]]*\])', '', text)
```